# How to use StatusChangeListener for validation in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using a binder to bind and validate a `TextField` and a `ComboBox`. To get notified of validation changes I add a StatusChangeListener to the binder. The listener checks whether `.hasValidationErrors()` returns false. However, after choosing a valid entry in the combobox, but a invalid entry in the textfield it returns false. So it returns false even though there are validation errors.
See below for a minimal example.

```
public class TestWindow extends Window {

    private final Binder<State> binder;

    public TestWindow() {
        this.binder  = new Binder<>();

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>("comboBox", List.of("A", "B"));
        TextField textField = new TextField("textField");

        this.binder.forField(comboBox).bind(State::getComboBox, State::setComboBox);
        this.binder.forField(textField)
                .withValidator(string -> string.length() > 3, "tmp")
                .bind(State::getName, State::setName);
        this.binder.addStatusChangeListener( status -> System.err.println(status.hasValidationErrors()));

        setContent(new VerticalLayout(comboBox, textField));
    }


    private class State {
        private String name;
        private String comboBox;

        public State(String name, String comboBox) {
            this.name = name;
            this.comboBox = comboBox;
        }

        public String getComboBox() {
            return this.comboBox;
        }

        public void setComboBox(String comboBox) {
            this.comboBox = comboBox;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

After entering a string that is too short in the textfield and selecting something in the combobox I would expect `true` to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just checking whether the value of the recently changed component is valid or not. If you want to check if there are any validation errors for your bound components, use `binder.isValid()`.

```
 binder.addStatusChangeListener(status -> System.err.println(binder.isValid()));
```

Note that your boolean is inverted now.

You can find a lot of usefull examples in the official documentation:
[Binding Data to Forms](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html)